# How can I add more android compatibility to my react native bluetooth app?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am working on a react native app that uses the `react-native-ble-plx` package to scan for bluetooth devices. I have run into an issue where the bluetooth functionality will only work on certain android devices.

There seems to be a trend where the app has not worked correctly on Samsung and Google phones. The app will run on the devices but when I get the scanning screen nothing shows up. Some devices are also unable to even download the device because of compatibility issues, however I believe this may be an unrelated issue involving the android sdk.

Has anyone else run into this problem? If so, how did you fix it?

**Application Details**
Target SDK: 31
Gradle: 7.1.1
`react-native`: 0.69.5
`react-native-ble-plx`: ^2.0.3
`@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx`: 3.0.0

**NOTE**: The app was originally in Expo and was ejected to start adding bluetooth capabilities. The `@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx` package was used before ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried React Native Bluetooth Classic? https://kenjdavidson.com/react-native-bluetooth-classic/
Maybe you won't have any problems with it.

Comment: I attempted to use this package and encountered the same issue from before. Is there possibly a setting in Android Studio that shows what architectures are supported for the app?